# Как правильно повесить клик javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть такой код https://jsfiddle.net/b9zg73Ld/50/, при клике срабатывает анимация стрелки(их будет 2), но срабатывает через раз, помоги разобраться? в javascript я новичек

```js
let iconButtonPrev = document.querySelector(".portfolio__arrow-prev");
let iconButtonNext = document.querySelector(".portfolio__arrow-next");
if (iconButtonNext) {
  iconButtonNext.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    iconButtonNext.classList.toggle("_active");
  });
};

if (iconButtonPrev) {
  iconButtonPrev.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    iconButtonPrev.classList.toggle("_active");
  });
};
```

```css
.portfolio__arrows {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translate(0px, -50%);
  width: calc(100% + 0px);
  z-index: 5;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 100px;
}

.portfolio__arrow-prev {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transform: scale3d(-1, 1, 1);
}

.characters {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 7px solid #ffd434;
  position: relative;
}

.characters::after {
  border: medium solid transparent;
  content: "";
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border-color: #ffd434 rgba(255, 212, 52, 0) rgba(255, 212, 52, 0);
  border-width: 30px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-left: -30px;
}

.portfolio__arrow-prev::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -35px 0 0 0;
  width: 35px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 0 35px 35px 0;
  background: rgba(111, 148, 182, 0.15);
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.portfolio__arrow-prev::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  right: 50%;
  left: auto;
  margin: -35px 0 0 0;
  width: 35px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 35px 0 0 35px;
  background: rgba(111, 148, 182, 0.15);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
}

.portfolio__icon-next ::before {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #ccba96;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.cbutton--effect-lazar-inverted {
  transform: scale3d(-1, 1, 1);
}

.portfolio__arrow-prev._active::before {
  -webkit-animation: anim-effect-lazar-1 0.8s ease-out forwards;
  animation: anim-effect-lazar-1 0.8s ease-out forwards;
}

.portfolio__arrow-prev._active::after {
  -webkit-animation: anim-effect-lazar-2 0.8s ease-out forwards;
  animation: anim-effect-lazar-2 0.8s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes anim-effect-lazar-1 {
  0%,
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
    transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes anim-effect-lazar-2 {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio__arrows">
  <button class="portfolio__arrow-prev desktop-swiper-button-prev desktop-swiper-button swiper-button cbutton--effect-lazar-inverted">
 <div class="characters"></div>
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавляем класс при клике. Вешаем eventListener для прослушивание анимации. И когда анимация закончилась удаляем класс active. Ты можешь сделать вот так (Анимация будет срабатывать каждый раз):

```
if (iconButtonPrev) {
    iconButtonPrev.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      iconButtonPrev.classList.add('_active');
    });
};


// Отслеживаем окончание анимации
iconButtonPrev.addEventListener("animationend", AnimationHandler, false);

function AnimationHandler () {
  // Удаляем класс с анимацией
  iconButtonPrev.classList.remove('_active');
  
}
```

Извиняюсь за излишний комментарий. Побольше гугли по CSS у тебя там есть вещи которые являются излишними.
Подобно этому:

```
width: calc(100% + 0px);
```